# Determine the Fourier expansion

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

This is a problem from my exam:

> A periodic function is defined by: $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
>        -1 & \textrm{ for }x\in[-\pi,\pi)\setminus\{0\} \\
>        0 & \textrm{ for }x=0 \\    \end{cases}\space , \space\space\space f(x+2π)=f(x)$$ Determine the Fourier expansion for
>   f(x).

Can I use the improper integral to solve the problem? If not, could you tell me how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing a function at a finite number of points in $[-\pi,\pi]$ does not change the Riemann integral. So the Fourier series of $f$ is the same as the Fourier series for the function that is identically $1$. The Fourier series of the function that is identically $1$ is the constant function $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is even and $2\pi$ periodic so you only need to evaluate the cosine coefficients : $$a_0(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0} -\,\mathrm{d}t+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} -\,\mathrm{d}t=-1$$
Indeed $f$ is discontinuous in only one point so $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Also $\forall n>0$ :
$$a_n(f) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \cos\left(nt\right)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0} -\cos\left(nt\right)\,\mathrm{d}t+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} -\cos\left(nt\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\=-\dfrac{\sin\left({\pi}n\right)}{n}-\dfrac{\sin\left({\pi}n\right)}{n}=-\dfrac{2\sin\left({\pi}n\right)}{n}=0$$

So the Fourier expansion of $f$ in $x$ is :
$$-1$$